# grep: input file ">":System cannot find the file specified

Tags: c++, grep

when I tried to execute a grep command in c++, I got the following error:
grep: Input file: ">":System cannot find the file specified

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

```
         wchar_t* grepArg= L"\"D:\\grep\" -f \"C:\\Users\\ic014733\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\patterns.tmp\" \"D:\\LOG2014_10_05.LOG\" >\"D:\\share\\result.txt\"";

        if ( !CreateProcessW(NULL, grepArg, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi) )
        {
            DWORD errorMessageID = ::GetLastError();

        }
        else 
        {
            DWORD res = WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
            TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0);                   
            PostThreadMessage(pi.dwThreadId, WM_QUIT, 0, 0) ;

            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
            CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

        }
```

Comment: yes,all the files exist. Error is like, grep considers '>' too as input file

Comment: What if you also escape `>`? Not sure how this should work.

Comment: Is a space missed after the `>`?

Comment: Windows `CreateProcess` is not a shell, it won't interpret redirections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave the answer in your comment : *Error is like, grep considers '>' too as input file*. Of course it does! Why should it not?

Let me explain a little: When you write `grep -f strings_file file > result` at a shell prompt (or cmd prompt under Windows), **the shell** parses the input line, indentifies the `>` redirection and processes the redirection:

- open `result` file
- start program `grep` with arguments (or command line for Windows) `-f strings_file file` **and standard output redirected to `result`**

But you are just starting the grep program with all the arguments in its command line, so no redirection can happen.

So what can you do? As none of your path contains spaces, you could just make `cmd.exe` do the redirection for you :

```
wchar_t* grepArg= L"cmd.exe /C \"D:\\grep -f C:\\Users\\ic014733\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\patterns.tmp D:\\LOG2014_10_05.LOG > D:\\share\\result.txt";
```

That means that you start a new `cmd.exe` program with two parameters: `/c` saying *execute that* and your original command enclosed in quotes. But I never found the way to cleanly include quotes in quotes in Windows. That's the reason why I removed all the inner quotes from your command. It was possible because there was no space in any path.

The alternative would be to do the redirection by hand: open the output file, pass its handle in the `hStdOutput` member of `si` and declare it by setting `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` in `dwFlags` member of same struct:

```
wchar_t* grepArg= L"\"D:\\grep\" -f \"C:\\Users\\ic014733\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\patterns.tmp\" \"D:\\LOG2014_10_05.LOG\"";

HANDLE hstdout = CreateFile("D:\\share\\result.txt", "GENERIC_WRITE", 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
// control hstdout is not null...
si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
si.hStdOutput = hstdout;
si.hStdInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); // stdinput and stderr unchanged
si.hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);

if ( !CreateProcessW(NULL, grepArg, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi) ) {
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this well descriptive answer. I could guess the error, but I did not understand the reason behind it and the solution.. Let me try the solutions ..